# Apache POI XWPF : How create a group of line?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm new on Poi. I try make a group shape composite with drawing line.
On LibreOffice doc I can make but with Poi seem be more difficult.

the exemple :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing about shapes in `apache poi`'s `XWPF` except charts up to now. But there is `com.microsoft.schemas.vml` which is able creating VML graphics for Microsoft Office files. Those graphics also are supported by Microsoft Word.

Creating the graphic itself is not as complicated as it is drawn from an VML path. So only knowledge about [VML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) is needed. But inserting the graphic into the Word document will need usage of the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` and `com.microsoft.schemas.vml.*` classes and needs knowledge about the internal XML structure of a `*.docx` file.

I hope you can get the principle from the following complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;

import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup;
import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateWordPathShape {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String boxWidth = "100pt";
  String boxHeight = "100pt";
  String posLeft = "150pt";
  String posTop = "0pt";

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body text: ");

  CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

  CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.setCoordsize("21600,21600");
  ctShape.setPath2("m21600,0 l0,0 l0,21600 l21600,21600 e");
  //path: from 0,0 (top left) move to 21600,0 (top right), line to 0,0 (top left), line to 0,21600 (bottom left), line to 21600,21600 (bottom right), end

  ctShape.setStyle("position:absolute"
   +";top:" + posTop
   +";left:" + posLeft
   +";width:" + boxWidth
   +";height:" + boxHeight
  );

  Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordPathShape.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();

 }
}
```

This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas as mentioned in [Apache POI FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Here is an example for a method to put a VML line shape into a `XWPFDocument`:

```
 private static void createLineShape(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String coordsize, String vmlPath, String strokecolor, String style) throws Exception {
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup ctGroup = com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.setCoordsize(coordsize);
  ctShape.setPath2(vmlPath);
  ctShape.setStrokecolor(strokecolor);
  ctShape.setStyle(style);
  org.w3c.dom.Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);  
 }
```

It can get called like so:

```
...
XWPFParagraph paragraph = ...
...
createLineShape(paragraph, "21600,21600", "m21600,0 l0,0 l0,21600 l21600,21600 e", "#FF0000", "position:absolute;left:0;width:100pt;height:100pt");
...
```

Comment: thx for your reply : ) and exemple !