# XWPF POI adding shape line to top and bottom of every page

Tags: apache-poi, position, shapes, diagonal, xwpf

How to adding shape line to top and bottom of every document page. Which document have more pages. In image was i give yellow circle. thanks

[image]

```java
public static XWPFRun GaRing (XWPFParagraph paragraph, String posisi, String warna) throws Exception {
    
    String boxWidth = "100pt";
    String boxHeight = "100pt";
    String posLeft = "-10pt";
    String posTop = "";
    String Path2="";

    if (posisi.equals ("atas")) {
        posTop = "-10pt";
        Path2="m 0,5000 l 20000,0 e"; //atas
    }
    else {
        posTop = "10pt";
        Path2="m 0,0 l 20000,5000 e"; //bawah
    }
    
    CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
    CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
    ctShape.setCoordsize("21600,21600");
    ctShape.setPath2(Path2); 
    ctShape.setStrokecolor(warna);
    ctShape.setStyle("position:absolute"
               +";top:" + posTop
               +";left:" + posLeft
            //   +";width:" + boxWidth
            //   +";height:" + boxHeight
            );
    Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
    CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
    
    XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  

    CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
    cTR.addNewPict();
    cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

    return run;

}
```

index.jsp:

```java
  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run;  

  GaRing (paragraph, "atas", "#FF0000");

  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body text: ");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  
  GaRing (paragraph, "bawah", "#FF0000");

  FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordPathShape.docx");
  doc.write(out1);
  out1.close();
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604410/apache-poi-xwpf-how-create-a-group-of-line/70607928#70607928 for how to create a line shape in Word.

Comment: what about line color. i use ctShape.setLineStyleColor(0,0,255), error..

Comment: The method setLineStyleColor(int, int, int) is undefined for the type CTShape

Comment: `ctShape.setStrokecolor("#FF0000");`

Comment: color solved. And how to set, the shape in every page, lihe header footer, but the position not in header footer

Comment: This sentence no sense ;-). Please edit your question. Show by code what you have now. And tell us how the result does not match your requirements.

Comment: i update my script, please check.

Comment: Yes, but what is the problem you have using that code? "adding shape line to top and bottom of every document page" screams to usage of  header and footer. So why not using header and footer?

Answer (score 0):

See [Apache POI XWPF : How create a group of line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604410/apache-poi-xwpf-how-create-a-group-of-line/70607928#70607928) for how to create a line shape in Word.

A method to create a line shape at position of a given paragraph and using a VML path to describe the line could look like so:

```java
 private static void createLineShape(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String coordsize, String vmlPath, String strokecolor, String style) throws Exception {
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup ctGroup = com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.setCoordsize(coordsize);
  ctShape.setPath2(vmlPath);
  ctShape.setStrokecolor(strokecolor);
  ctShape.setStyle(style);
  org.w3c.dom.Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);  
 }
```

Note the `String style` describes the size and the position absolute to the given paragraph. For example: `"position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100pt;height:50pt"`.

Your requirement "adding shape line to top and bottom of every document page" screams to usage of header and footer. So why not using header and footer?

If you don't have control over the page breaks, then you cannot predict where the pages change. Then top and bottom line shapes would must be in page header and footer.

Following method would do that:

```java
 private static void createHeaderAndFooter(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  createLineShape(paragraph, "21600,21600", "m 0,21600 l 21600,0 e", "#FF0000", "position:absolute;left:0;top:-14pt;width:100pt;height:50pt");

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  createLineShape(paragraph, "21600,21600", "m 0,0 l 21600,21600 e", "#FF0000", "position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100pt;height:50pt");
 }
```

If you have control over the page breaks, you can set the top line shape and the bottom line shape directly in the text flow. Then the line shapes in header and footer are not needed.

Following shows a complete example to show both:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTNumbering;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;

import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup;
import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class CreateWordLineMarkingPagesAndParagraphs {
    
 static String cTAbstractNumDecimalXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"1\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2.%3\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";
    
 private static BigInteger createNumbering(XWPFDocument document, String abstractNumXML) throws Exception {
  CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(abstractNumXML);
  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);
  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
  BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);
  return numID;
 }
    
 private static void setBorderLeftColor(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String rgb) {
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() == null) return; // no paragraph properties = no borders
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr() == null) return; // no paragraph border 
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr().getLeft() == null) return; // no left border
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr().getLeft().setColor(rgb);
 }
 
 private static void setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(double tabStopPosInInches, XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewTabs().addNewTab();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().getTabArray(0).setVal(
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc.LEFT);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().getTabArray(0).setLeader(
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabTlc.HYPHEN);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().getTabArray(0).setPos(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(tabStopPosInInches * 1440))); 
 }
 
 private static void setPageSize(XWPFDocument document, double widthInInches, double heightInInches, 
  double topPageMarginInInches, double bottomPageMarginInInches, double leftPageMarginInInches, double rightPageMarginInInches, 
  double headerHeightInInches, double footerHeightInInches) {
  if (document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr() == null) document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  if (document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgSz() == null) document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewPgSz();
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgSz().setW(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(widthInInches * 1440)));
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgSz().setH(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(heightInInches * 1440)));
  if (document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar() == null) document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewPgMar();
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setTop(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(topPageMarginInInches * 1440)));
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setBottom(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(bottomPageMarginInInches * 1440)));
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setLeft(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(leftPageMarginInInches * 1440)));
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setRight(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(rightPageMarginInInches * 1440))); 
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setHeader(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(headerHeightInInches * 1440))); 
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setFooter(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(footerHeightInInches * 1440))); 
 }
 
 private static void createOnePageOfText(XWPFDocument document, BigInteger numIDDecimalList) throws Exception {  
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  // If you have control over the page breaks, you can set the top line directly in the text flow. Then the top line in footer can be removed.
  createLineShape(paragraph, "21600,21600", "m 0,21600 l 21600,0 e", "#FF0000", "position:absolute;left:0;top:-50pt;width:100pt;height:50pt");
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH); // alingment justify
  // set tab stop at position 6.5 inches 
  // (right page margin for page size letter and 1 inch left and right page margin)
  setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
  setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.addTab();
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH); // alingment justify
   setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
   paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
   setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
   paragraph.setIndentationLeft((int)Math.round(0.5 * 1440));
   run = paragraph.createRun();  
   run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. Additional this paragraph is left indented. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. Additional this paragraph is left indented.");
   run.addTab();

   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numIDDecimalList);
   paragraph.setNumILvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
   paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
   setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
   paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
   setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
   run = paragraph.createRun();  
   run.setText("This is a numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines. This is a numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines.");
   run.addTab();
  
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numIDDecimalList);
   paragraph.setNumILvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
   paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
   setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
   paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
   setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
   run=paragraph.createRun();  
   run.setText("This is another numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines. This is another numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines.");
   run.addTab();
  
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH); 
   setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
   paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
   setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
   run = paragraph.createRun();  
   run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
   run.addTab();
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  // If you have control over the page breaks, you can set the bottom line directly in the text flow. Then the bottom line in footer can be removed.
  createLineShape(paragraph, "21600,21600", "m 0,0 l 21600,21600 e", "#FF0000", "position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100pt;height:50pt");

 }
 
 private static void createLineShape(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String coordsize, String vmlPath, String strokecolor, String style) throws Exception {
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup ctGroup = com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.setCoordsize(coordsize);
  ctShape.setPath2(vmlPath);
  ctShape.setStrokecolor(strokecolor);
  ctShape.setStyle(style);
  org.w3c.dom.Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);  
 }

 private static void createHeaderAndFooter(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  createLineShape(paragraph, "21600,21600", "m 0,21600 l 21600,0 e", "#FF0000", "position:absolute;left:0;top:-14pt;width:100pt;height:50pt");

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  createLineShape(paragraph, "21600,21600", "m 0,0 l 21600,21600 e", "#FF0000", "position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100pt;height:50pt");
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  BigInteger numIDDecimalList = createNumbering(document, cTAbstractNumDecimalXML);
  
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The header line of the whole document.");
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("blah, blubb, barr...");
  
  // This method creates exactly one page of text.
  createOnePageOfText(document, numIDDecimalList);
  
  // add page break
  document.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
  
  createOnePageOfText(document, numIDDecimalList);
  
  // If you don't have control over the page breaks, then you cannot predict where the pages change. Then top and bottom lines would must be in page header and footer.
  //createHeaderAndFooter(document);

  // set page size letter format (8.5 x 11 inches) and 1 inch top, bottom, left and right page margin and .5 inch header and footer height
  setPageSize(document, 8.5, 11d, 1d, 1d, 1d, 1d, .5d, .5d);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordLineMarkingPagesAndParagraphs.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: the problem, I dont know length of text.

Comment: example, i have more text paragraph when i type in ms word have 3 page. I dont know which text are in bottom of first page, second page etc

Comment: @Eko: Then only using header and footer will be possible. This is also shown in example. Simply remove `//` from code line `//createHeaderAndFooter(document);`.